# Get values from request to array WebAPi

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I'm new in Web APi, and I have app with token based authorization and users roles.
I have controller which must get all users with role 'users'.
Controller looks like:

```
public class UsersController : ApiController
            {
                public IEnumerable<ApplicationUser> GetUsersRoleUser ()
                {
                    var context = new ApplicationDbContext();
                    var users = context.Users.Where(x => x.Roles.Select(y => y.RoleId).Contains("601fd2b9-4a7f-4063-a831-e15978f05657")).ToList();
            return users;
    }}
```

That's good, and I get answer:

**[was edited for @Ferri comment]**

```
[{"Claims":[],
"Logins":[],
"Roles":[{"UserId":"2d9e98d4-2203-4f68-b8eb-6cac3c94cbd7","RoleId":"601fd2b9-4a7f-4063-a831-e15978f05657"}],
"Email":null,
"EmailConfirmed":false,
"PasswordHash":"AGMPpGJcGtD5",
"SecurityStamp":"ef896d77-e82a-4018-9023-1bf2e967e7bc",
"PhoneNumber":"+375445907729",
"PhoneNumberConfirmed":false,
"TwoFactorEnabled":false,
"LockoutEndDateUtc":null,
"LockoutEnabled":false,
"AccessFailedCount":0,
"Id":"2d9e98d4-2203-4f68-b8eb-6cac3c94cbd7",
"UserName":"sanya"},
{and another}]
```

How can I get array with values only "UserName"?

Comment: Could you paste in this question your full json result?

Comment: Okay, I pasted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [*DTO*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) design pattern. In your case, an anonymous type should be enough:

```
context.Users
            .Where(x => x.Roles.Select(y => y.RoleId).Contains("601fd2b9-4a7f-4063-a831-e15978f05657"))
            // Project each user into a DTO which just 
            // UserName property...
            .Select(x => new { UserName = x.UserName })
            .ToList()
```

Comment: Thank you! But I can't return an anonymous type?

Comment: Oh yes, I try) But Visual studio show me error about can't covert "System.Collections.Generic.List<<anonymous type: string UserName>>" into "System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<AppName.Models.ApplicstionUser>". Omg, what I do wrong?)

Comment: @feofan Change your return value from `IEnumerable<ApplicationUser>` to `IEnumerable<object>`!